# Interact with webmatrix database using PHP

Tags: php, sql, database, connection, webmatrix

I am having trouble using my Webmatrix database. I would like to insert data into the database with a registration page written in PHP.

When I created my database the "web.config" file was created. How can I use the connectionString from the "web.config" file in my PHP to be able to connect to the database?

***Connection string from my web.config file:***

```
     <connectionStrings>
    <add connectionString="server=localhost;uid=root;database=sitedetest;Pwd=123" name="sitedetest" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**I tried this:**

***config.php***

```
       <?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '123';
$dbname = 'sitedetest';
?>
```

***In the registration page:***

```
include 'config.php';
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass)
        or die ('Error connecting to mysql');
    mysql_select_db($dbname);
```

But when I try using the registration form, I always get the 'Error connecting to mysql' message

Thank you for your time

Comment: Change your error to `or die("Could not connect : " . mysql_error());` let's see what is the real error

Comment: Is the database on the same server as your php engine ?